# Groovy is not recognised as internal or external command

Tags: groovy

I downloaded and installed [groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/)

But if I type `groovy` in the cmd i get

```
'groovy' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: What is the operating system you are using? Windows, Mac, Linux? Please add the specific version, it might help. Also, what is the specific install method you have used?

Comment: @petre I used the windows installer .......anyways I got the answer now so.....

Answer (score 4):

To Solve this Problem Follow following Steps::

Right Click on **This PC**>>go to Properties>>Go to Advance System Setting(at Left)

In This Window

Go to **Environment Variables**

Click on **New** Enter variable name **'groovy'**.

For path goto this pc and select the path where groovy is installed for Example::

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-3.0.0\bin
>   paste your path instead of my path in your variable path field.

now press save and ok.
Restart your VS Code editor..

Now, It's Working.....!

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a problem in the windows installer.

Edit path settings manually; replace %GROOVY_HOME% by the directory name

D:>path 
PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\Groovy\bin

Now the groovy command *does* work.